# Valgrind errors: heap overflow for pollfds struct

Tags: c, linux, valgrind, polling

Running valgrind throws me this massive error for each element of pollfd(fd,events,revents):

```
==14524== 286699 errors in context 6 of 6:
==14524== Syscall param poll(ufds.fd) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==14524==    at 0x4984D47: poll (poll.c:29)
==14524==    by 0x10AD7C: connmgr_listen (connmgr.c:95)
==14524==    by 0x109549: main (main.c:12)
==14524==  Address 0x4a97a10 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==14524==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14524==    by 0x10B285: element_copy (connmgr.c:196)
==14524==    by 0x10A07F: dpl_insert_at_index (dplist.c:117)
==14524==    by 0x10AE6E: connmgr_listen (connmgr.c:113)
==14524==    by 0x109549: main (main.c:12)
```

It has to do with the fact that I have a struct called connection which hold my TCP sockets and it contains a struct called socket_descriptor which holds the pollfds information for polling (fs,events,revents). I call the polling function which throws the error(line 95):

```
int rc = poll(&(connection->socket_descriptor), nr_connections, 0);
```

It's caused by this block here in which I initialise a new connection and add it to my double pointed list of connections.

```
          if (connection->socket_descriptor.revents & POLLIN))
          { // add latest connection from listening node
                connection_t *new_node = calloc(1,sizeof(connection));
                if (tcp_wait_for_connection(connection->socket, &client) != TCP_NO_ERROR)
                      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                tcp_get_sd(client, &(new_node->socket_descriptor.fd)); //gets fd of the socket descriptor
                new_node->socket_descriptor.events = POLLIN | POLLRDHUP;
                new_node->socket_descriptor.revents = 0;
                new_node->socket = client;
                dpl_insert_at_index(connections, (void *)new_node, nr_connections, true);
                free(new_node);
          }
```

I tried calloc so that the pollfd elements would have an address but it didn't work. I understand that it probably comes from a struct within a struct but I don't know how to fix it.

The struct of my connection:

```
struct connection
{
      time_t ts;
      tcpsock_t *socket;
      fds_t socket_descriptor;
};
```

Comment: If `connections` is some sort of list pointer and `dpl_insert_at_index` will add/insert `new_node` into the list, you [probably] do _not_ want to do `free(new_node)`

Comment: connections is a pointer to an element in a list so you're right, but could you explain more. If I don't free it there I get a memleak. and it seems to function fine outside of valgrind.

Comment: As I mentioned, if the function _inserts_ `new_node` into the list [_without_ copying/cloning/duplicating it first], then the list will have a pointer to it. If we then try to use _that_ pointer it will point to memory that you've already freed (a no-no). Try compiling with `-fsanitize=address` and run the program (_without_ `valgrind`) and see what it says. It may say [eventually]: "use after free". It will check for misuse as it happens. Note that if you leave off the `free`, then `valgrind` might complain at program end because you never cleaned up the _list_ properly--a different issue.

Comment: `valgrind` _will_ complain about a memleak _if_ you do the early/failure exit: `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` (i.e.) it complains about the `new_node` that you just got from `calloc` but didn't put anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about -fsanitize=address. It showed me a heap overflow error. From my understanding that means that when I try to read the socket descriptor, it doesn't have as much memory allocated to it as it needs but I don't understand why since I did the calloc. I'll add my struct to the question.

Comment: A guess ... You are using a library from https://github.com/Jerry-Jincheng/systemsoftware ??? The reason you have to do `free` is because you are passing `true` as the last arg to `dpl_insert_at_index`. This tells it to make a copy (IMO, the copy function may be problematic). Try using `false` and _not_ calling `free`

Comment: You define `fds_t socket_descriptor;` and pass a pointer to it to `poll`. But, `poll` wants a pointer to a `struct pollfd` _array_. So, the typedef `fds_t` is non-standard. Please _edit_ your question and post [all of] your code in a _single_ code block here. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example but also http://sscce.org/ The code should compile cleanly and be downloadable/runnable by responders here. _If_ you _are_ using the systemsoftware git code, you needn't include that.

Comment: It is the same project so I have my own libraries. They can be found here: https://github.com/asraujan/Systems-Software . The question I'm asking relates to connmgr.c